# How to get data in the href tag in iOS?

Tags: html, ios, objective-c, iphone, uitextview

Currently i am working on an iOS app which requires me to parse the JSON data(announcements within our company) and show in a grouped tableview, i have already tried - stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString and tried to show the links in UITextView but i am not getting the result i needed. I want to show only the data from the href tag which contains some links where users can click on them to see announcements. Below is the code i have written . Can anybody point me in the right direction ?

```
if (indexPath.section == 0) {

    UILabel *issueStatus = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 2, cell.frame.size.width, 15)];
    [issueStatus setText:[[tmpArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"title"]];
    issueStatus.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];
    [cell.contentView addSubview:issueStatus];



    UITextView *issueStatus2 = [[UITextView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 20, cell.frame.size.width, 60)];
    NSString *str1 = [[[[[[[tmpArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"body"] valueForKey:@"view"] valueForKey:@"value"] stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"<p>" withString:@""] stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"<a href=\"" withString:@"" ] stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"class=external-link rel=nofollow>" withString:@""];
    [issueStatus2 setText:str1];
    issueStatus2.editable = NO;
    issueStatus2.scrollEnabled = NO;
    issueStatus2.dataDetectorTypes = UIDataDetectorTypeLink;
    [cell.contentView addSubview:issueStatus2];
```

and below is the sample JSON data for a key-value pair i am getting out of JSON , Can any one help me on how to get only the link in the href tag to be displayed in my UITextView?

```
{
id: "14975323",
type: "page", 
status: "current",
title: "How to Re-Open a Resolved Ticket",
body: {
view: {
value: "<p><a    href="https://drive.google.com/a/domain.com/file/d/0B9TSHFNjUGsjYmV2a3pzcTFOWXM/edit" class="external-link" rel="nofollow">https://drive.google.com/a/domain.com/file/d/0B9TSHFNjUGsjYmV2a3pzcTFOWXM/edit</a></p>",
representation: "view",
_expandable: {
content: "/rest/api/content/14975323"
}
}
_expandable: {
editor: "",
export_view: "",
anonymous_export_view: "",
storage: ""
}
}
```

Comment: it looks like you're missing the double quotations in your last invocation of stringByReplacingOccurencesOfString method. If you don't add those quotations it won't replace the string.

Comment: OMG, seven levels of `[` ... ']' and 350 characters all none statement on one line! Surely you do not expect anyone to read and understand that line.

Comment: BTW, using literal subscripts `tmpArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"body"] valueForKey:@"view"] valueForKey:@"value"]` can be replaced with `tmpArray[indexPath.row][@"body"][@"view"][@"value"]`.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a regular expression to get the URL from the JSON. For example,

```
NSString *pattern = @"((?:http|https)(?::\\/{2}[\\w]+)(?:[\\/|\\.]?)(?:[^\\s""]*))";
NSRange range = [yourString rangeOfString:pattern options:NSRegularExpressionSearch];
//credits for the simpler solution go to @Zaph
self.textView.text = [yourString substringWithRange:range];
```

(The pattern might need some tweaking, I can't currently test it; it also assumes there is only one URL is your JSON)

Comment: This is an example where all three lines could be written in a one line statement—but be having several statements it is easy to follow and understand. There is also debug-ability because the intermediate results can be easily examined.